# Parameter can be accessed and invalidated by the call

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In the CppCon 2015 youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA , "Writing Good C++14... By Default", Herb Sutter explains around 59:10 about parameter lifetimes that are checked by a concept version of the code analysis tool. I’m trying to reproduce that particular warning with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.5.5. With the following code:

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<int> gsp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
void f(int*){}

void Example5()
{
    f(gsp.get());
}

int main()
{
    Example5();
}
```

In the video the message `Parameter ‘result.get’ can be accessed and invalidated by the call to ‘f’` is given by the analysis tool. But my analysis tool does not show such a message. Also not when I turn on all messages. To me it seems a valuable warning. Does anybody know why it is removed? Is it removed?

Comment: They had very ambitious goals for code analysis back in 2015.  Didn't make the cut.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Unfortunate. Are still developments going on in the area of analysis tooling? I am quite interested. And I guess many C++ programmers should be interested as well.